# Recursive repaint detected in popup window

Tags: qt, popup, repaint, qwidget

I have a QPushButton that will open new window on clicked.

```
void showNewWindow()
{
  PopupWindow *popup = new PopupWindow();
  popup->show();
}
```

And PopupWindow is declared as following:

```
class PopupWindow : public QWidget {
Q_OBJECT

public:
  PopupWindow(QWidget* parent);
  void setContent(QString content) { this->content = content; }
  QString getContent() { return content; }
private:
  QString content;
private slots:
  void handleContinue();
  void handleRunToEnd();
```

};

Then I implement a its constructor:

```
PopupWindow::PopupWindow(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent)
{
  QHBoxLayout *hlayout = new QHBoxLayout();
  QWidget *buttonWidget = new QWidget();
  QPushButton *btnContinue = new QPushButton();
  btnContinue->setText("Continue");
  QPushButton *btnRunEnd = new QPushButton();
  btnRunEnd->setText("Run till completion");
  buttonWidget->setLayout(hlayout);
  hlayout->addWidget(btnContinue);
  hlayout->addWidget(btnRunEnd);
  connect(btnContinue,SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(handleContinue()));
  connect(btnRunEnd,SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(handleRunToEnd()));
  QTextEdit *html = new QTextEdit();
  html->setReadOnly(true);
  html->setText("AAAA");
  QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
  this->setLayout(layout);
  layout->addWidget(html);
  layout->addWidget(buttonWidget); 
}
```

My problem: whenever I click on the "Continue" or "Run till completion" buttons on Popup Window. The app crashed. I could see the error as following:

> QApplication: Object event filter cannot be in a different thread.
>
> QApplication: Object event filter cannot be in a different thread.
>
> QApplication: Object event filter cannot be in a different thread.
>
> QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected

Please, help me to resolve this.

Comment: I think the problem is with `handleContinue` and `handleRunToEnd` slots. You should also show them.

Comment: Nothing in these functions, I didn't implement it. Just prototype:

    void PopupWindow::handleContinue()
    {
    
    }
    void PopupWindow::handleRunToEnd()
    {
     
    }

Comment: You can't access GUI widgets from any thread except the thread that created QApplication. Please update your QApplication instantiation.

Comment: The GUI widgets (PopupWindow) can be shown correctly. I think there is some issue with signal handler

Comment: what happen when you remove the `connect()`?

Comment: The application still crashed when I removed connect()

Comment: Anyway, I found the reason. I created new Popup in an worker thread not main thread.